# Need help - center a button in wordpress when viewed in responsive layout

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive

The website is freetorun.net in wordpress.  When viewed on mobile devices the gold "Sign up" button is not centered on the screen.

I was thinking that changing the font-size to 14px in the CSS would fix it:

```
.large.custom-button span:visited {
font-size: 14px;
padding: 9px 14px 9px;
```

}

This code is not working though.
The target HTML is this:

```
<a class="large custom-button align-btn-right" href="http://freetorun.net/wordpress/choose/" title="Register Today!"><span style="background-color:#DAA520; color:#26354A">to start running faster, farther and<br> injury free SIGN UP for a clinic!</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout on mobile has lots of issues with padding and floated elements. Changing the font size won't help with positioning.

Firstly the div with class `social_media_top widget_text substitute_widget_class` should probably be full width, and `text-align: center;`

You also need to remove the `float: right` on the gold button.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I did not solve this.  And the code provided above didnt either.  But the guys who wrote the U-Design theme gave me this and it is much better.

```
#top-elements .social_media_top {
clear: both;
float: right;
margin-left: -150px;
margin-top: -20px;
padding: 0 20px 0 0;
```

}

/* Mobile Screen ( smaller than 480px )*/
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

```
#top-elements .large.custom-button span, 
#top-elements .large.custom-button span:visited {
    font-size: 14px;
}

#top-elements .social_media_top {
    padding: 0;
}
```

}